# Is it acceptable to say 'quite occasionally'

Tags: grammaticality

I quite occasionally play chess. Is it acceptable to say 'quite occasionally'

Comment: Why not replace "quite occasionally" with a single word - such as *frequently*?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by this? To me, it's unclear whether you're using the phrase to mean "quite often" or "quite intermittently". That ambiguity may, in fact, be a reason not to use this phrase.

Comment: I guess it's just established idiomatic usage - I can't think of any sound semantic or grammatical argument against it, but *quite occasionally* doesn't sound at all good to me. On the other hand, I'm fine with ***very** occasionally* and *quite **often***. It might be something to do with "negatively polarity", but I really don't know.

Comment: ...note that OP's usage [has quite occasionally occurred in print](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+quite+occasionally%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), so I think it would be a brave pedant who would maintain that it's indisputably "incorrect". It's just "odd", and thus definitely best avoided by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it is not grammatically incorrect, *occasionally* generally refers to something that happens with a lesser frequency, ie. *from time to time*. Qualifying it with *quite* is meant to increase the frequency, which moves away from the normal use of the word, and so a different choice of words would sound better.  I would use *frequently*.